# Relation between refractive index and lateral displacement

Tags: optics, refraction

If light bends more towards normal on increase in refractive index then how does lateral shift increase?
Let the medium be a rectangular glass slab.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The lateral shift is $$t\frac{\sin(\theta_i-\theta_r)}{cos\theta_r}$$

where $\theta_i$ is the angle of the incident ray, $\theta_r$  the angle of refracted ray and $t$ the thinkness of the glass slab.

See also [this website](http://kea.kar.nic.in/Outreach/Physics/Geometrical_Optics.pdf#:%7E:text=LATERAL%20SHIFT%20When%20a%20ray%20of%20light%20is,ray%20and%20emergent%20ray%20is%20called%20%E2%80%9Clateral%20shift%E2%80%99%E2%80%99.)